# C# DataGridView cell not allow for decimals

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am new to C# developments. This editable DataGridView has 5 columns and last column allow for decimals numbers.

But my problem is How it allow  only integers.
I hope you guys can answer me this question

```
private void productionStockDataGridViewEcs_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.KeyPress +=
        new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyPress);
    }

private void Control_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    int column = productionStockDataGridViewEcs.CurrentCellAddress.X;
    int row = productionStockDataGridViewEcs.CurrentCellAddress.Y;
    if (column == 4)
    {
        AllowDecimal(productionStockDataGridViewEcs.Rows[row].Cells["Quntity"], e, 10, 3);
    }

}

private static void AllowDecimal(Control control, KeyPressEventArgs e, int noOfIntegers, int noOfPrecisions)
        {
            string decimalSeparator = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator;

            if ((47 < e.KeyChar && e.KeyChar < 58) || e.KeyChar == 8 || e.KeyChar.ToString() == decimalSeparator)
            {
                if (e.KeyChar.ToString() == decimalSeparator && control.Text != "")
                {
                    if (control.Text.Contains(decimalSeparator))
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CheckLengthForDecimal(control, e, noOfIntegers, noOfPrecisions);         //when double only ok
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    CheckLengthForDecimal(control, e, noOfIntegers, noOfPrecisions);           //when double only ok
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }


private static void CheckLengthForDecimal(DataGridViewCell cell, KeyPressEventArgs e, int noOfIntegers, int noOfPrecisions)
        {
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.Text = cell.Value.ToString();
            int cursorPosistion = textBox.SelectionStart;
            string decimalSeparator = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator;

.....................
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
 AllowDecimal(productionStockDataGridViewEcs.EditingControl, e, 10, 3);
```

For your example you use DataGridView cell `productionStockDataGridViewEcs.Rows[row].Cells["Quntity"]` for `AllowDecimal`. Put `productionStockDataGridViewEcs.EditingControl` for AllowDecimal method